# Command object fails validation with getter not associated to property (Grails 3.1, 3.2)

Tags: grails

I have a controller like this:

```
class DemoController {

    def index() {
        DemoCommand cmd = new DemoCommand(demoAmount: 'foo')
        render cmd.validate() ? "Validation successful" : "Validation failed, ${cmd.errors}"
    }
}

class DemoCommand implements Validateable {
    String demoAmount

    static constraints = {
        demoAmount nullable: false
    }

    Long getDemoAmountAsLong() {
        demoAmount?.isNumber() ? new Long(demoAmount) : null
    }
}
```

Hitting the index action shows validation failed, stating demoAmountAsLong cannot be null. There were a couple bugs reported in 3.1.2 (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9754) on this issue but looked like they were resolved. I've tested this in both 3.1.11 and 3.2.11 with the same results. I must be missing something? I've tried making the getter method transient, or adding `static transients = ['demoAmountAsLong']` without luck.

Comment: add `demoAmountAsLong nullable:true` to your constraints

Comment: Yes, that works, which surprises me. From how I read the ticket I referenced above, getter methods without a property shouldn't be subject to validation.

Comment: @JeffKays Create an issue and include a sample application that reproduces the problem

Comment: @JamesKleeh Issue created, https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10859